# jQuery shove-out drawers: click works (kinda), what about hover?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating some jQuery shove-out drawers - that's my name for a collapsed div that expands when a click or hover event is triggered. This is actually part of a larger menu system. Anyway, there are two a elements, and when you click on one, a drawer opens with some content in it. I currently have it set where if you click once it opens, and a second click closes. However, since there is another link that does basically the same thing right next to it, I want the drawer to stay open when toggling between them. Currently, I can only get it to work once if you click the first link to open, then click the second link to toggle the content, then click either link again, the drawer closes. This probably doesn't make a whole lot of sense, so have a look at some code.

Here's the actual JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.drawercontrol').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dindex = $(this).data("index");
        $('.drawer').removeClass('active');
        $("div[data-target='" + dindex + "']").addClass('active');
        if ($('#drawerarea').hasClass('closed')) {
            $('#drawerarea').toggleClass('closed');
            //$("div[data-target='" + dindex + "']").addClass('pop');
        }
        if ($("div[data-target='" + dindex + "']").hasClass('pop')) {
            $('#drawerarea').toggleClass('closed');
            $('.drawer').removeClass('pop');
        } else {
            $("div[data-target='" + dindex + "']").addClass('pop');
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the basic HTML framework:

```
<div id="topbox">
    <a href="#" class="drawercontrol" data-index="1">Drawer One</a>
     <a href="#" class="drawercontrol" data-index="2">Drawer Two</a>
</div>
<div id="drawerarea" class="closed">
    <div class="drawer active" data-target="1">Drawer One is Active</div>
    <div class="drawer" data-target="2">Drawer Two is Active</div>
</div>
<div id="bottombox"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
#topbox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
#topbox a {
    margin: 10px;
}
#drawerarea {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#drawerarea.closed {
    height: 0px;
}
.drawer {
    display: none;
}
.drawer.active {
    display: block;
}
#bottombox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

All in one: http://jsfiddle.net/HbA8f/2/

There's one commented line in the JavaScript, which I thought would improve the click function, but for some reason, that causes the drawer to not work at all.

If anyone has any ideas about how I can improve the click functionality here, to make it as user-friendly as possible, that would be great.

Also, the client wants hover functionality as well. If anyone has any ideas about that, that would be great also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about something like this?

```
$(function () {
    $('a.drawercontrol').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var index = jQuery(this).index(),
            targetDrawer = jQuery('.drawer').eq(index);

        if (targetDrawer.hasClass('active')) {
            targetDrawer.hide().removeClass('active');
        } else {
           targetDrawer.show().addClass('active').siblings().hide().removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Every time you click on a link, you check wether the related drawer (using indexes, instead of data) is open or not. If it's open, you close it. If not, you open it and close all his siblings.

There is also a CSS change: there's no need to close or open the drawers parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/HbA8f/4/

To have hover functionality, maybe something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/HbA8f/5/

h

Comment: Your click solution is fantastic, thanks a million. However, the hover is a problem. It works fine for opening the drawers, but does not allow for any interaction with the drawers. Moving the mouse to click within a drawer causes the drawer to disappear.

Comment: Then you can try to mix the two scripts. To begin with, instead of a hover effect, bind a mouseenter event (that way we get rid of the actions when the user 'leaves' the link). Then bind another action with a click and the same logic we had on the first script. Like in here:

http://jsfiddle.net/HbA8f/9/